# How blazor reads webapi in real time and displays it？

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, blazor

There is a collection, obtained from the  service,Data comes from web api:

```
 var _lists= await ModbusService.ModbusGetListAsync();
```

I converted it to a dictionary type：

```
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
           
                modbuslists = await ModbusService.ModbusGetListAsync();
                modbusDict = modbuslists.ToDictionary(
                    t => t.VarName, t => t.Value);
                await base.OnInitializedAsync();
          
           
        }
```

Now, in the blazor page, if you want to get the value of any key in real time, try a while loop:

```
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                modbuslists = await ModbusService.ModbusGetListAsync();
                modbusDict = modbuslists.ToDictionary(
                    t => t.VarName, t => t.Value);
                await base.OnInitializedAsync();
            }
        }
```

The page can't be displayed directly. What should I do? Read the data about once every second to refresh the page.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/rendering?view=aspnetcore-5.0#receiving-a-call-from-something-external-to-the-blazor-rendering-and-event-handling-system

Comment: I don´t get the point of an infinite loop here. How should that *ever* return? You´re awaiting again and again and again...

Comment: I think I know how to do it, thanks！